# how do I assign the defined permissions to the right policies and controller methods in Spatie/Laravel-permission?

Tags: php, laravel, policy, laravel-permission, laravel-authorization

This may seem a simple problem, but I could not find a solution either in Laravel policy documentation or in Spatie/Laravel-permission documentation.
Here is the problem:
This is how I've assigned permissions to certain roles in PermissionSeeder.php:

```
 public function run()
    {
        // Reset cached roles and permissions
        app()[PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();

        // create permissions
        Permission::create(['name' => 'view own tickets']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'view all tickets']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'forward a ticket']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'close a ticket']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'write a ticket']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'assign permissions to roles']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'hide a ticket']);


        // create roles and assign existing permissions
        $role1 = Role::create(['name' => 'staff']);
        $role1->givePermissionTo('view own tickets');
        $role1->givePermissionTo('forward a ticket');
        $role1->givePermissionTo('close a ticket');
        $role1->givePermissionTo('write a ticket');

        $role2 = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
        $role2->givePermissionTo('view own tickets');
        $role2->givePermissionTo('forward a ticket');
        $role2->givePermissionTo('close a ticket');
        $role2->givePermissionTo('write a ticket');
        $role2->givePermissionTo('hide a ticket');
        $role2->givePermissionTo('view all tickets');

        $role3 = Role::create(['name' => 'Super-Admin']);
    }
```

Now let me give you an example of how my controller method for forwarding a method looks:

```
class TicketController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * forward a ticket to another user.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function forwardTo(Request $request)
    {
        $ticket = TicketTitle::find($request->ticket_id);
        $ticket->forwarded_to = $request->user_id;
        $ticket->status = TicketTitle::STATUS_FORWARDED;
        $ticket->save();
        return \response($ticket, 200);
    }
}
```

It is necessary to first verify that the user has the permission to forward a ticket before executing this method... Could you please explain how to do this?
If I have to define a policy, given the name of my method and my permission, what should the policy be called?
I also checked similar questions, but none of them had the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(auth()->user()->hasPermissionTo('forward a ticket')){

  $ticket->forwarded_to = $request->user_id;

};
```

try this one.commit for further issues

Comment: It works! thank you. but is there no need to write a policy, when I use Spatie/Laravel-permission package?@Hafiz

Comment: ok. thank you a lot if you vote for me

Answer (score 0):

You can from method: has Permission To Use as follows: ‌

```
$user->hasPermissionTo('edit articles')
```